# Mysql Fetching Data from database one column from 1st table & second table 3 columns

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, `optionvalues` & `valprice`.

I have **opt_id** & **prod_id** as same in both table.

**Table `optionvalues`:**

```
id opt_id item_id  value   value_img
 1    1       5     Big       img1
 2    1       6     Small     img1
```

**Table `valprice`:**

```
price_id    price_dir          price    prod_id        val_id   item_id
  1                +             10        1               1       7
  2                -             5         1               2       7
```

**My query:**

```sql
SELECT  op.value, vp.price_dir, vp.prod_id, vp.price, vp.val_id
from optionvalues op, valprice vp
where op.opt_id=1 and vp.prod_id=1
```

**Output:**

```
Big +10
Big -5
Small +10
Smaall -5
```

Whereas I want this

```
Big +10
Small -5
```

Comment: Your query selects five columns, but your result only has two columns? Errr... what?! Are you able to explain this?

Comment: i want to select values with opt_id=1 & price, price_dir, from valprice where prod_id=1;

Comment: i want values big & small with associated values of price & price_dir ..

Comment: but i am getting like Big +10 Big -5 Small +10 Small -5

Comment: @DaviJass: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell MySQL how the tables should be joined:

```
SELECT op.value, vp.price_dir, vp.prod_id, vp.price, vp.val_id
FROM   optionvalues op JOIN valprice vp ON vp.val_id = op.id
WHERE  op.opt_id=1 AND vp.prod_id=1
```

Read [this tutorial](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) for more information on SQL joins.

Comment: Thanx it really works... you saved me from trouble also from my boss Thank you so much

Comment: @DaviJass: No problem.  FYI, you should [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/161492) if they work for you; and also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) them if they're helpful!  :)

Comment: i am also in trouble for my ajax code i am bulilding a pizza site when user ticks the checkbox the price should update dynamically

Answer (score 0):

The query should be

```
SELECT  op.value, vp.price_dir, vp.prod_id, vp.price, vp.val_id
 from optionvalues op, valprice vp
 where op.opt_id=vp.prod_id and op.opt_id=1
```

Comment: i am also in trouble for my ajax code i am bulilding a pizza site when user ticks the checkbox the price should update dynamically

Comment: @DaviJass - For that please post a separate question mentioning the code you have written and what is not working in that. www.stackoverflow.com is to help you solve your problems if you have some piece of code. You cannot ask vague things like your above comment. I hope you get it :)

Comment: @DaviJass - What problem are you actually facing ? Please give more details. I would suggest you to create a new question altogether !

Comment: function update(str)
{
alert(str);

    var x=document.getElementById("val_id").value;
 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

 var myString = xmlhttp.responseText; 
    document.getElementById("value1").innerHTML=myString;
 
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php?u=+str+&itm_id=x",true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>